# Apply same formula to every cell

Tags: google-sheets, formula, cell

I have a sheet with several numbers, which I want to convert to percentage. These are scores imported from a form, where the maximum score is 5.

According to the bellow image, the cell B2, I applied a basic formula `=(3/5)*100%` to convert three to 60%.

[image]

In order to avoid copy and paste the same formula into all cells, is there any formula to find all the cells and apply its value, divide per 5 and multiple per 100%? I thought something similar to Javascript such as `(this/5)*100%`.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZtqJaXy1pHkjk1sywGfSodo0FcOoLlkou79cZBk-jmU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

you could treat it as array and on Sheet2 use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Sheet1!B2:AA="";;(Sheet1!B2:AA/5)*100%))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hQ7fjZ037JTLZYxmMC2iZRiLqAnvBf8cgfykATCyL8Y/edit#gid=174674135)

Comment: In this solution the formula uses [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) which let you return and use a range of cell values rather than individual cells. In this case it first checks with [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) if the cell from ```Sheet1``` has a value and if it does then it applies the formula over it.

Answer (score 0):

I've also looked for a solution to this for some time.

I don't think it's possible as a cell can only hold one value and the moment you try to change that value, it will delete the value.

Your best bet is to create a different table on the same sheet that references the specified values, then copy and paste the results (values only).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a second Sheet, then in cell B2 of Sheet2 use the formula `=Sheet1!B2/5*100%`.

Then copy the formula to all cells of Sheet2.